# PHP Regex preg_match showing unusual behavior

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Here is the pattern:

```
$urlpattern = '%[^http://][^https://][\w]+(-[\w]+)*(\.[\w]+(-[\w]+)*)*\.[\w]{1,6}(\.[\w]{1,6})*[^/]%';
```

I have encountered a strange bug that boggles me.

When I search against a string like `'power-tool-world.com'` it gimps it and returns `'ower-tool-world.com'` (removes the p) but when I use any other letter(not tested on EVERY other letter) it works fine, so `'cower-tool-world.com'` returns `'cower-tool-world.com'` can someone please help me understand why, but more importantly give me a solution that wouldn't cause this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is in the first part. When you use square brackets you match one of the characters inside them so `[http://]` matches h, t, p, : and /, and these characters will be excluded from the next matching group. You should use `^(http://|https://)?` instead.

Comment: Not quite. `[^http://]` matches any character *except* h, t, p, : or /. And of course `^(https?://)?` would be the preferable alternative.

Comment: No, although you might be on the right track, your solution returns a false, saying that power-tool-world.com does not match

Comment: Your point makes sense because both h & t return the same thing but what is the correct solution?

Comment: @Tim Pietzcker you are right but i've interpreted it as a typo because i thought that he was looking for a string that optionally starts with http:// or https://.